# Updating records using stored procedure in sqldatasource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, sqldatasource

i have datasource which has an sp called for update and been binded to gridview. i want while updating it should use the sp and update table.
Below is my design code.

```
 < asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
        DataKeyNames="Title" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableModelValidation="True"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ShowFooter="True" Width="1000" AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="10" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">  
        < AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />  
        < Columns>  
            < asp:TemplateField HeaerText="Title">  
                < ItemTemplate>  
                    < asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>  
                < /ItemTemplate>  
            < /asp:TemplateField>  
            < asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quote">  
                < ItemTemplate>  
                    <%# Eval("Quote") %>  
                < /ItemTemplate>  
                < EditItemTemplate>  
                    < asp:TextBox ID="txtEditQuote" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quote") %>'></asp:TextBox>  
                < /EditItemTemplate>  
            < /asp:TemplateField>  
            < asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quote Link">   
                < ItemTemplate>  
                    < %# Eval("QuoteLink") %>  
                < /ItemTemplate>  
                < EditItemTemplate>  
                     < asp:TextBox ID="txtEditQuoteLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuoteLink") %>'>< /asp:TextBox>  
                < /EditItemTemplate>   
             < /asp:TemplateField>  
            < asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Published">  
                < ItemTemplate>  
                    < asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Published")) %>' 
                        Enabled="false" />  
                < /ItemTemplate>  
                < EditItemTemplate>  
                    < asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("Published") %>'  Enabled="true" />  
                < /EditItemTemplate>  
            < /asp:TemplateField>  
            < asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PublishedDate">  
                < ItemTemplate>  
                    < %# Convert.ToDateTime(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PublishedDate")).ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") %>  
                < /ItemTemplate>  
                < EditItemTemplate>  
                    < asp:TextBox ID="txtEditPublishedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PublishedDate") %>'>< /asp:TextBox>  
                < /EditItemTemplate>  
            < /asp:TemplateField>  
            < asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Commands">  
                < ItemTemplate>  
                    < asp:Button runat="server" ID="Edit" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />  
                    < asp:Button runat="server" ID="Delete" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />  
                < /ItemTemplate>  
                < EditItemTemplate>  
                    < asp:Button runat="server" ID="Update" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />  
                    < asp:Button runat="server" ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />  
                < /EditItemTemplate>  
            < /asp:TemplateField>  
        < /Columns>  
        < EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />  
        < FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />  
        < HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="White" />  
        < PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />  
        < RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />  
        < SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />  
    < /asp:GridView>  
    < asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" 
        SelectCommand= "SELECT [TITLE], [QUOTE], [QUOTELINK], [PUBLISHED], [PUBLISHEDDATE] FROM [DBO].[QUOTES]"
        UpdateCommand="sp_ModifyQuotes" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">  
        < UpdateParameters>  
            < asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="String" />  
            < asp:Parameter Name="Quote" Type="String" />  
            < asp:Parameter Name="QuoteLink" Type="String" />  
            < asp:Parameter Name="Published" Type="Boolean" />   
            < asp:Parameter Name="PublishDate" Type="DateTime" />  
            < asp:Parameter Name="Modify" Type="String" DefaultValue="Update" />  
        < /UpdateParameters>  
    < /asp:SqlDataSource>
```

and below is my SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ModifyQuotes]
    @Title varchar(max),
    @Quote varchar(max),
    @QuoteLink varchar(max),
    @Published Bit,
    @PublishDate DateTime,
    @Modify varchar(10)

AS
BEGIN
    Declare @QuoteId int
    IF (@Modify = 'Add')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.QUOTES
        (
            Title,
            Quote,
            QuoteLink,
            Published,
            PublishedDate
        )
        values
        (
            @Title,
            @Quote,
            @QuoteLink,
            @Published,
            @PublishDate
        )
        SET @QuoteId = @@IDENTITY
        If @Published = 1
        BEGIN
            UPDATE dbo.Quotes SET Published = 0 WHERE Id <> @QuoteId AND Published = 1
        END
        --SELECT @QuoteId As ID
    END
    ELSE IF (@Modify = 'Update')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Quotes SET
        Quote = @Quote,
        QuoteLink = @QuoteLink,
        Published = @Published,
        PublishedDate = @PublishDate

        WHERE Title = @Title
        --SELECT '1' As ID

    END
    ELSE IF (@Modify = 'Delete')
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM dbo.Quotes
        WHERE Title = @Title

        --SELECT '1' As ID
    END
END
```

please any one help me how should i update my records when i try to update i gets an error saying:

> Procedure or function sp_ModifyQuotes
>   has too many arguments specified.

but i guess i have passed all proper parameters.

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler to capture the actual execute command sent to SQL?  That might give you an idea of where the extra parameter is coming from...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Modify parameter is in the INSERT/VALUES parts of your SP - basically they do not match.

Comment: @IrishChieftain: I created new SP, dedicated for update but still same issue: here's new SP
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_UpdateQuotes 
 @Title varchar(max),
 @Quote varchar(max),
 @QuoteLink varchar(max),
 @Published Bit,
 @PublishDate DateTime
AS
BEGIN
 UPDATE dbo.Quotes SET
 Quote = @Quote,
 QuoteLink = @QuoteLink,
 Published = @Published,
 PublishedDate = @PublishDate
 
 WHERE Title = @Title
 
 If @Published = 1
 BEGIN
  UPDATE dbo.Quotes SET Published = 0 WHERE Title <> @Title AND Published = 1
 END
END
GO

Comment: Make sure your new parameter list matches those in the <UpdateParameters> list - check the types as well; everything has to match

Comment: @IrishChieftain: It seems that was working fine on my local PC, but when i uploaded the same on my server, update button just does not works.. this had put me in trouble... Please help me out for this, the code, database, tables, sp's, everything is same

Comment: Is there an error message? Comment out any try/catches you have and see what it reports. Execute the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio to rule that out... do you have a staging server?

Comment: @IrishChieftain: I have a staging server, i am using dotnetnuke on that, on the site without dotnetnuke runs fine, even on stage, but on the same server, everything is same, just it has dotnetnuke installed, there i am unable to update, there is just no error, not even the button event is executed. i even tried using oncommand event and placed response message, but that too not working, because its not going inside the button events, dont know whats happening.

Comment: Re-register ASP.NET with aspnet_regiis -c  it sounds like the aspnet_client files are corrupted

Comment: @IrishCheiftain: can you tell me the steps for registering aspnet file

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx On my machine the aspnet_regiis.exe tool is in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 but it could be on a different drive on your machine... plus go to the appropriate version folder for ASPNET

Comment: @IrishCheiftain: Just need to double click on the above file or need to install using command prompt.

Comment: @IrishCheiftain: i used command prompt with aspnet_regiis -c command, it throws an error saying IIS is in 64bit mode and application is in 32bit mode and thus not compatible.